# Insert text after matching "pattern"

Tags: regex, text, insert

I have this: `wares.php?id=5&x1=4&x2=33&x3=1`
What I want to do is to insert `[1:` before 4 in `x1=4`  and `]` after the 4 (before &). the number in `x1=4` can be any natural number.
Is there any way to do this? What tools are required (maybe some kind of text editor with regex)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sed`

```
echo "wares.php?id=5&x1=4&x2=33&x3=1" | sed "s|x1=\([0-9][0-9]*\)|x1=[1:\1]|"
```

gives

```
wares.php?id=5&x1=[1:4]&x2=33&x3=1
```

Comment: can this be used with files (txt for example)?

Comment: It certainly can. `cat file | sed "s|x1=\([0-9][0-9]*\)|x1=[1:\1]|"` will output the new file, or `sed -i "s|x1=\([0-9][0-9]*\)|x1=[1:\1]|" file` will edit the file in place.

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++ you can do:

1. search for `(x1=)(\d+)`
2. replace by `\1[1:\2]`

With perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/(x1=)(\d+)/$1\[1:$2\]/;' < file_to_modify
```